# How do i use Telemetry data saved in Azure blobs to build reports?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-insights

Azure Application Insights does not allow telemetry data retention for more then few days, however it has option called "Continuous export" which exports data into Azure Storage Blobs, so question is how do I build reports using data stored in blobs?   Is there a way to use Azure Application Insight's Reporting system itself to point to blob storage as "Data Source" and see reports ?

How are others later building reports on Azure Application Insights data that is exported using "Continuous export" option ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can import the data from the Continuous Export into Azure Data Explorer (ADX). [Here](https://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2020/11/automatically-move-your-application-insights-data-into-azure-data-explorer/) is a full article that explains this. In ADX you can keep the data as long as you want to.

Then, you can use the [cross-query feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/azure-monitor-data-explorer-proxy) of Azure Monitor to also query data from ADX and thus you get a unified view of current and historical data.